# android save bitmap in sd card

Tags: android, bitmap

i save the bitmap in sd card with the following code

```
String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
        File myDir = new File(root + "/saved_images");
        myDir.mkdirs();
        Random generator = new Random();
        int n = 10000;
        n = generator.nextInt(n);

        String fname = "Image" +".jpg";
       // String imageInSD1 = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() +"/saved_images/" +  fname;
        File file = new File (myDir, fname);
       // if (file.exists ()) file.delete ();
        try {
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
            bitmap_profile1.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
            out.flush();
            out.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

its working fine but issue is this i am doing this in loop which run every 5 sec  the image slowly slowly demage . i want to save the image only one time how can i check this if image is already in sd card then do not save the image i have only one name for image image change but its name remain same please tell i want to save the one image for only one time if bitmap value change then image save othervise image not save.

Comment: I would post some links, but there are _so_ many https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=android%20check%20if%20file%20exists%20on%20sd%20card

Comment: i have issue with bitmap which change not file name

Comment: You want to know if there is an image saved to the SD card that matches the one you have loaded as a Bitmap, and if it exists _not_ save it? That would take a good bit of work. Android just sees those as files, you would have to load all of them, get their byte values, and then compare. It would not be efficient in any way, shape, or form.

Comment: Your code does not store to SD crard but to external strage. `getExternalStorageDirectory()`.

Comment: ok thanks i got it

Answer (score 0):

The function you're looking for is file.exists()

After creating your File file, go

```
if(!file.exists())
    try{...
        ....
```

**Edit: Full code**

```
String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
    File myDir = new File(root + "/saved_images");
    myDir.mkdirs();
    Random generator = new Random();
    int n = 10000;
    n = generator.nextInt(n);

    String fname = "Image" +".jpg";
    File file = new File (myDir, fname);
    if (file.exists ())    //  only try to save picture if it doesn't exist already
        try {
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
            bitmap_profile1.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
            out.flush();
            out.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: i have a bitmap which change not file name i want when same bitmap is in  folder then do not save

Comment: When I get home I will give you a full code solution.

Comment: Same as yours, but only save if the file doesn't already exist with that name.

Comment: bro i have only bitmap issue not file name

Comment: how can i check if bitmap is equal to other bitmap?